# how to configure pom.xml to working with ear project as dependency

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb

I`m new here and i trying to configure maven to working with ear project as dependency of other war project: To imaginate my idea i include the following image[image]

I wonder how to configure poms.xml of this two war projects
(doggle and expert) to get possiblity calling enterprise beans of core.ear project. Simply adding dependency to pom.xml not working correctly. I think I need use some maven plugin or do something addtiotional.

Could somebody help me or give some instructions what I should do to include in pom.xml of each war project ear project and than call EJB bean? I Will grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Convert your war project into jar projects and create two new war projects that depend on the jar project. Now your ear project can depend on the two jar projects.